# Is $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{2Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{5Z}$ as groups?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Is  $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{2Z}$ is not  isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{5Z}$ ?

How can i check this? the elements of  $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{2Z}$ is  be of form

$$\frac{p}{q} +2\mathbb{Z}$$ where $p$ and $q$ are Integers. similarly the elements in $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{5Z}$  is of form
$$\frac{p'}{q'} +5\mathbb{Z}$$

I have no idea how can i proceed it further, can i draw a isomorphism form  $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{2Z}$ to  $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{5Z}$?

Please Help!

Thankyou.

Comment: Are you looking for an isomorphism of groups or of rings?

Comment: I am looking for group isomorphism.

Comment: You have an isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, x\mapsto \frac{5}{2}x$. Now check that this extends to an isomorphism between your desired groups. Indeed, you can compose $\varphi$ with the projection onto $\mathbb{Q}/5\mathbb{Z}$, compute the kernel and use the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Does it should be $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{5Z},$ and the  kernel will be $2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can think of $\mathbb{Q}/5\mathbb{Z}$ as glueing together $0$ and $5$ and similarly $\mathbb{Q}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as glueing together $0$ and $2$. Thus, scaling by $5/2$ should do the job (and it actually does).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You have an isomorphism
$$\varphi:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, x\mapsto \frac{5}{2}x.$$

Now check that this extends to an isomorphism between your desired groups. Indeed, you can compose $\varphi$ with the projection onto $\mathbb{Q}/5\mathbb{Z}$, compute the kernel and use the correct isomorphism theorem for groups to conclude.